# How to “normalize” an age-of-death probability distribution with respect to births in corresponding years?

Tags: probability, mortality

Let's suppose that we know about the age of death of n people (this being a representative sample of a given population), all died in the same year H.

We can define $P(x)$, the probability of dying at each age $x$ in the year H, as the percentage of people in the sample dead at the age of $x$:
$$P(x)=\frac{m(x)}{n}$$
where $m(x)$ is the number of people in the sample dead at the age of $x$.

Let's say that this distribution looks something like this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha6eN.png

---

At this point one can see that even if the curve is globally quite "smooth", there do are a few local irregolarities (like little "hills" and "valleys") and so a first operation to correct this behaviour could be to "normalize" the generic value $P(\bar{x})$ with respect to the births in the corresponding year H-$\bar{x}$ (all these birth data, from year H-$x_{-}$ to year H-$x_{+}$, are supposed to be well known).

**What could it be the best mathematical method to do so?**

I thought of multiplying each generic value $P(\bar{x})$ by the fraction
$$\frac{b.a.}{b(H-\bar{x})}$$
where $b.a.$ is the mean number of births per year, from year H-$x_{-}$ to year H-$x_{+}$, and $b(H-\bar{x})$ is the number of births in the year $H-\bar{x}$; re-normalizing after that so that all the $P(x)$s sums to one again.

Still, this procedure only seems to give the curve more asperities.